# Selenium XPath, selecting button with same class name

Tags: selenium, xpath, python-3.8

I have html which looks as following:

```
<button onclick="newInputScenario()" class="btn btn-primary">New...</button>&nbsp;
  <button onclick="uploadInputScenario()" class="btn btn-primary">Upload...</button>&nbsp;
  <button onclick="diffScenarios('idb');" class="btn btn-primary">Diff...</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button onclick="newUserScenario()" class="btn btn-primary">New UDS...</button>
```

But all the above have same `class` name.

I have been using the following code but it won't work for above as I need to click the second button `Upload...`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\chromedriver'  # change path as needed
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary']"))).click()
```

How do I modify my code above to be able to click `Upload...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below code.

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary'][.='Upload...']"))).click()
```

You can also use the below xpath.

```
//button[@class='btn btn-primary'][2]
//button[@onclick='uploadInputScenario()']
```